# How to make sure a silent push notification will never be seen by Android OS?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending a silent push notification every how with Firebase cloud function.

With iOS, the notification is never showed up to the user.

With Android, it depends. Some devices show the notification, some don't.

I want to avoid the end user to see that silent notification because it is used to triggered some code behind the scene that he does not need to know.

Any clue about the configuration that I could set in the cloud function OR maybe something that could be added to the Kotlin code?

Here the javascript code that generate the silent push

```
const message = {
    "data": {
        "something": somethingType.toString()
    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "apns-priority": 5,
                "content-available": true,
            }
        }
    },
    "tokens": uniqueTokens
};
```

the "data" is not something the application needs to display. It is there to tell the code the goal of that silent notification. This is for internal use. Not for end-user.

Comment: Since your message only contains a `data` property, and no `notification` property, it should actually **not** be automatically displayed by the system (see docs on [message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options?authuser=0)). Can you edit your question to explain in what cases your `data` only message is being shown? Are you sure this is not happening from your own code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I will need to check with the Android team. But still, why the behavior is not constant with different brands?